# Display typed text within context of code

Tags: html, forms

In a simple webpage, I am trying to grab the value of an input field as it's being typed and display it simultaneously within the context of code.

So a user could past an URL into the input field and it immediately update the code displayed, so he can easily copy the update code. For example:

```
<input type='text' name='typedURL'>
Here is your code: <a href="value of typedURL">copy this</a>
```

I searched all over the internet and am under the impression that the best solution is using this:

```
<form onsubmit="return false" onkeyup="o.value = a.value">
<input name="a" id="a" type="text" step="any">
<br>
Here is your code:
<code>
<a href="<output name="o" for="a b"></output>">Copy this code</a>
</form>
```

But I can't get it to output the value PLUS the surrounding code.

Comment: The code seems to do what I would expect it to do: https://jsfiddle.net/vtm5yrm7/  Am I misunderstanding something in the question?

Comment: Perhaps my example was unclear. The problem is how to make the output display code, for example:

`<form onsubmit="return false" onkeyup="o.value = a.value">
<input name="a" id="a" type="text" step="any">
<br>
Here is your code:
<code><a href="<output name="o" for="a"></output>">copy this</a></code>
</form>`

In other words, the output show up in the context of code.

Comment: That's making even less sense to me now.  What is that `href` value even supposed to *do*?

Comment: It's supposed to display the full a href code for the user to copy and paste elsewhere.

So someone who doesn't know how to code a link, can just paste the URL in the input field and the code is automatically generated (displayed) below.

Pretty sure I'm approaching this from the most complicated angle. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was able to get close using this:

`<div class='printchatbox' id='printchatbox'></div>
<input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput' 
    onkeyUp="document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = this.value" />`

But again, how would I add the <a href> code to the output?

Comment: Do you want do that if I input put www.google.it the link will is: <a href="www.google.it"></a>

Comment: Yes Blind, exactly.

Comment: I can create your code, Can you wait any minute?

Comment: Yes, certainly, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do selecting input value (with `querySelector` and `.value`), and change attribute `href` in JS replacing with `.value`.
Here the code:

```js
  var input = document.querySelector(".valore");
  var link = document.getElementById("href");
  input.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
       link.innerHTML = input.value;
       link.href = link.innerHTML;
  });
```

```html
  <input type="text" class="valore">
  <a href="#" id="href"></a>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank yoU!

Comment: I'm happy to have help you! If I've help you give my answers like better

Comment: What would be the alternative to display the code to user? For example, the user be able to copy the update text:

`<a href="#" id="href"></a>` 

instead of being a clickable link?

Comment: Do you means a button that if you click it copy the href?

Comment: Yes, a button would be an option. 

I was thinking:

`<pre>
   <code>
    &lt;a href="#" id="href"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
   <code>
 </pre>`

Comment: You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for all the help Blind.

Comment: Gosh I wish I could. I have no idea how to do that.